# Meteor table cells dynamic values from helper loading multiple times

Tags: html, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

I need to display the values of a session object inside a table’s cells so that each row of the table cells represent each one of the object’s field Plan (see screenshot) and field price
[image]

I have created a helper that returns the object,

```
  Template.stepFour.helpers({
    Plans(){
      console.log('result',Session.get("Plans"))
      return Session.get("Plans")
    },
```

and have used this helper in meteor html template as follows

```
<div class="gr-3 gr-12@tablet gr-12@mobile gr-12@mobile">
                                        <div class="featurecol">
                                            <div class="titlerow">
                                                <div class="package1">
                                                    <p>Product 1
                                                    <br>
                                                    </p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            {{ #each Plans }}
                                            <div class="featuretablerow">
                                                <div><i class="fas fa-check"></i> {{ this.Plan.[0]}}</div>
                                            </div>
                                            {{/each}}

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="gr-3 gr-12@tablet gr-12@mobile gr-12@mobile">
                                            <div class="featurecol">
                                                <div class="titlerow">
                                                    <div class="package2">
                                                        <p>Product 2
                                                        <br>
                                                        </p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                {{ #each Plans }}
                                                <div class="featuretablerow">
                                                    {{#if isNonZeroTx }}
                                                    <div><i class="fas fa-check"></i> {{this.Plan.[1]}}</div>
                                                    {{else}}
                                                    <div><i class="fas fa-times"></i></div>
                                                    {{/if}}
                                                </div>
                                                {{/each}}
                                            </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="gr-3 gr-12@tablet gr-12@mobile gr-12@mobile">
                                            <div class="featurecol">
                                                <div class="titlerow">
                                                    <div class="package5">
                                                        <p>Price
                                                        <br>
                                                        <span class="texttype__tiny">euros</span>
                                                        </p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                {{ #each Plans }}
                                                <div class="featuretablerow">
                                                    <div>{{ this.price }}</div>
                                                </div>
                                                {{/each}}
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
```

this has as a result to load multiple times the object therefore I notice that there are delays in displaying the values, what it the right way to write it?
thank you

Comment: Use `#with` context and then `#each this` to call the helper only once

Comment: thanks @Jankapunkt is it possible to provide an example because I am trying with both with and each but I cannot get it

Comment: after some searching around I was able to make it work with #with and #each using table, I will update with the right code thank you @Jankapunkt for the tip!!